# NetBeans "Go To Declaration" (F12) work-around in mis-configured JavaServer Faces (JSF)

Tags: jsf, netbeans, navigation, utilities

Is there a "shortcut key" work-around (e.g. macro, plugin, etc.) to navigate into a Java method from a JSF page in NetBeans (v. 7.4)?

*Context (less relevant):*

*Problem*: JSF navigation features, esp. "Go To Declaration," in my slightly mis-configured NetBeans environment are mostly broken.  I'm gonna lose my mind if I have to keep copying method name > find symbol > paste method name > get matches > look back at parent classes/interfaces > scroll to match > select match.

*Config Fail*: Won't fix IDE/env configuration (to enable JSF navigation) for now.  Initial attempts failed (plus DevLead asked me not to touch it).  It's some combination of NetBeans/J2EE/JSF/PriceFaces/Gradle/GlassFish.

*Analogous Work-Around*: Within Visual Studio, macros that match strings to "Go to Implementation" (when declarations bring you to interface)

*Psychology*: Sequences of learned repetitive fine-motor movements (e.g. a longer sequence of UI navigation commands) are part of "implicit procedural memory."  Mine is very weak.